# Best Practice to Format Large List Comprehension?

Tags: python, formatting, list-comprehension

I have a collection of rather large objects from which I only need 4 data points, they look like the following:

```
{
    'date': '01/01/1900'
    'info': {'contact': 'Jane Doe',
             'id': 298342,
             'address': '123 Street Rd.'},
    'account': {'name': 'Random Event Name',
                'id': 9623075},
    'guest_count': 523,
    'rooms': [{'name': 'Room A',
               'id': 209353,
               'capacity': 300},
              {'name': 'Room B',
               'id': 630923,
               'capacity': 50}],
    'start_time': '10:00:00',
    'end_time': '15:45:00',
              .
              .
              .
}
```

I have a simple for loop to iterate through the objects and pull the information out that I need:

```
info = []
for event in events:

    start_time = event['start_time']

    location = 'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House'

    name = event['account']['name']

    guest_count = event['guest_count']

    info.append([start_time, location, name, guest_count])
```

Which I then converted to the following list comprehension:

```
info = [[event['start_time'], 'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House', event['account']['name'], event['guest_count']] for event in events['results']]
```

This definitely breaks the 80 character rule and can't seem to find any documentation on how to format variable heavy list comprehension.

This is what I ended up doing, but it still seems rather ugly:

```
sanitized_events = [
    [event['start_time'], 
    'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House', 
    event['account']['name'], 
    event['guest_count']] for event in events]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pieces of code are not supposed to be collapsed to a list comprehension. If you try and it seems to get more complex, then it is worth asking if it was a right path to begin with.

One path to consider is always a helper function

```
def _sanitize(event):
  location = 'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House'
  return (event['start_time'],
          location,
          event['account']['name'],
          event['guest_count'])

sanitized_events = [_sanitize(event) for event in events]
```

which splits the logic of list creation from the processing, thus making it easier to comprehend the high level idea, while being able to jump to details if needed.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this, but using a lamda function instead. I feel odd denoting a named function for something only going to be called once. <br/>
    `sanitation = lambda event: [event['start_time'], 'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House', event['account']['name'], event['guest_count']]`<br/>

   `return [sanitation(event) for event in events['results'] if 'results' in events]`

Comment: Note that you are not calling the function once, you call it in a loop. And in the end you did "name" your function - you even ended up using more characters to go through lambda definition :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
info = [[event['start_time'],
         'Offsite' if event['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite' else 'In-House',
         event['account']['name'],
         event['guest_count']] for event in events['results']]
```

Which I think is readable-enough.

[Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) is covered in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Note where it says:

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the line length limit up to 99 characters, provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters.

So you're not really limited to <80 characters (for code). I personally have found that 90 works well with almost all the tools I use (and coincidentally for posting code in the website).

Answer (score 0):

```
sanitized_events = \
[
    [ 
        event['start_time'],      
        
        'Offsite' if (event ['rooms'][0]['name'] == 'Offsite')
        else 'In-House',
                                
        event['account']['name']  
    ], 

    event['guest_count']
    
    for event in events
]
```

For nested complicated structures, is better to use the same convention used in c language for blocks: The open and close brackets have its own line and matching brackets are in the same column. The content of the list is indented.

Additionally surround multiline items with blank lines. Optionally separate the `for` clauses from the items with a blank line.